# Copy HTML table with structure to clipboard in angular

Tags: angular, html-table, copy, clipboard

I am trying to copy whole HTML table with its structure to clipboard in angular. The copy part is working fine but it is not following the exact table layout.

1. Table to Copy

   [image]
2. Copied Table

   [image]

Seems like it is following the layout of header correctly but data layout is wrong.

Methods being used to achieve this thing

```
selectNode(node){
    let range  =  document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(node)
    let select =  window.getSelection()
    select.removeAllRanges()
    select.addRange(range)
  }

  copy(){
    this.selectNode(this.queryTable.nativeElement);
    document.execCommand('copy');    
  }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="queryTable" class="table table-responsive-sm table-hover table-outline mb-0" #queryTable>
   <thead class="text-center no-padding" style="background: #0042be;">
       <tr class="querytableheaderstyling">
           <th *ngFor="let key of debugQueryData">{{key}}</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="text-center">
       <tr *ngFor="let value of debugResult | filter : filters.searchUsersText">
           <td *ngFor="let key of debugQueryData; index as i" style="padding:0px 10px !important"><div [innerHTML]="value[key]"></div></td>
       </tr>   
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

P.S: I cannot use DataTable in this scenario due to few reasons. I am using simple HTML based table so, please provide solutions which can work in this scenario.

Comment: You need the same css styles in order to make it look like the original table

Comment: Could you please elaborate your point?

Answer (score 0):

Check the raw values of what you copied, it seems you have there `/n` or something like that.

Try to add `nodeString.strip()` to remove any special chars in your data.

Or even remove all special chars from your copied input like this

```js
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I have edited the post and added HTML table. Please take a look at it and suggest something. Thank you